# Internal link starting with a slash

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have an org mode document containing headers that start with a slash (for italics), such as

```
* /This/ is my header
```

how can I create an internal link to this header? Since it starts with a slash, org thinks it looks like a file name.

(org mode 9.4.6, emacs 27.2)

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution. In the link, add an asterisk before the header name:

```
[[*/This/ is my header]]
```